# Selecting highest number (of 2 letters and number)

Tags: hive, hql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehm9s.png)

Hello,

1. I would like to create a rule that will run only on class_id=12 and the output shows all the class_ids I have in the table - what is the right way to achieve it?
2. 2. I have book_id consisting of 2 letters at first and numbers afterward.
      I would like to pick for each Student_id the highest book_id number (NV5602 - in the example above). How could I do it ?

**HQL**

Thanks

Comment: is book_id should be calculated as max in class_id=12 partition  or max in class_id=12 and  userid partition? Required output with better data example in TEXT format (not picture) will increase your chance to get good answer. Questions like this when one need to guess what is the ask exactly and also data example is in picture and one need to manually type it to reproduce - is a complete wasting of time

Answer (score 0):

Your first point is still not cleared. For 2nd point, you can try below -

```
SELECT Student_id, Book_id
  FROM (SELECT Student_id,
               Book_id,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUBSTR(Book_id, 3, LENGTH(Book_id)) DESC) RN
          FROM YOUR_TABLE) X
 WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: thanks! I have run this one and got a row number 1-3 for these 3 rows. For each student_id I would like the select the highest book_id (1). Thanks again

Comment: Did you run the whole query? You must get only 2 columns and only 1 row.

Comment: I don't know why I give me error on the where when I run it on HQL (cannot recognize input near 'where' 'rn' '=' in subquery source)

Comment: @Matias021, Can you try now?